# Integrate year in nested logit R

Tags: r

I want to make a nested logistic regression in R with the package mlogit

I test how producer's decision to enter organisations (14 organisations) or not is affected by different factors....

But I have question: How can I integrate the year variable in my regression (2005-2010)
because for example producer can be in specific organisation in 2005 but an other in 2006...

other question :Can I draw the tree decision in R?

Your help is very much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use regression, you need to use each year as a separate variable and set to 1 for actual year and to 0 for all others (thus making them separate **binary attributes**). E.g. you will have attributes:

```
att1, att2, att3, year2005, year2006, ..., year2012, ...
```

If you are going to use decision trees, you can represent years as **categorical attribute** (`factor`s in R).

And yes, it is possible to plot decision trees in R. Take a look at [**rpart**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/index.html) package ([usage examples](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html))

Comment: Thanks ffriend it's exactly what i look for.

Comment: to be sure: actual year 2005=1 and 2006=0,2007=0,2008=0,2009=0,2010=0? for each producer raw

Comment: Hi it's the same that year i must use organisation as separate variable: organisation 1=1 organisation 2= 0....? I have an other question: my members appear many times in row in my database it will not redundant?